# Hartree-Fock calculations of the states of Nitrogen molecule ion

Tags: quantum-chemistry, software

I was reading the third chapter of "Modern Quantum Chemistry" by A. Szabo and N. Ostlund about HF calculations, and in the end of the chapter it shows as an example a calculation on $\ce{N2}$ MOs. It's said that HF predicts that the $1\pi_{u}$ MO is higher in energy than the $3\sigma_{g}$, what we know to be wrong. There are two hypotheses to explain it: the negligence of the electronic correlation or of the relaxation effects. To test the effects of relaxation, UHF calculations are done for the ion $\ce{N2^+}$. The energies of the states $^{2}\Sigma_{g}$ and $^{2}\Pi_{u}$ of $\ce{N2^+}$ are computed and subtracted from the energy of $\ce{N2}$ ground state to compute the ionization potentials.

My question is about the determination of the energy of these two states of $\ce{N2^+}$ in practice using a program like Gaussian 09. The program computes the energy of the ground state, but how can I compute the energy of different states of a molecule? I know that there is a relation between the total energy and the energies of the MOs, so I suspect that I should use the MO energies to do this, but I don't know a way to do it using the output of Gaussian for example.

Comment: To calculate electronic excitations you need to use a non-variational scheme like CIS, CISD, TDDFT, EOMCCSD, etc. These are generally quite expensive and don’t even do a great job, but it can be quite illustrative. Gaussian will be perfectly happy to give you excited states with CISD if you ask for them.

Comment: Some programs, and I do not know whether Gaussian is among them, can restrict the symmetry of the molecule and thus force certain states by ruling out lower-lying states of a different symmetry. Note that this can also happen accidentally when the initial guess if of such a symmetry and the converging algorithm does not check for instabilities: basically, a saddle point instead of a minimum is found. The instability check is non-trivial and expensive.

Comment: Please keep in mind that depending on the actual revision of Gaussian, it is at least a 7 year old program with no support whatsoever. You should only be using it for the sake of reproducing old data and comparing it to new data. Symmetry isn't a key feature of Gaussian, I think it is limited to D2h. However, it should still be possible. Since this question is less about the chemistry, or theory, and more about the execution with a specific software, I suggest transferring it to [mattermodeling.se].